# Dynamically assign onsubmit validator

Tags: javascript

In my form I have the following

```
<script>
function validate(form)
{
   if(form.xyz.value=='') return false;
   return true;
}
</script>

<form onsubmit="return validate(this)">
  <input name="xyz">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

For some reason I have to assign my onsubmit listener dynamically.

I cound define

```
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit',validate);
```

But how to dynamically achieve `return validate(this)`

(I need pure JavaScript, not jQuery)

Comment: It's probably not related to your issue, but you should still fix the curly quotes in `onsubmit=”return validate(this)”`. On second thought, yeah, it's probably your problem. Testing your code in a jsFiddle shows that it works fine without the event listener.

Comment: `For some reason I have to assign my onsubmit listener dynamically.` What is the reason?

Comment: The reason is that my form is created by ExtJS dinamically, then I come after it and want to assign validator on this form that is created previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument passed to the event handler function is [the Event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event). If you want to pass a different value, then create a new function and pass it explicitly.

```
function validateEventHandler(event) {
    return validate(this);
}

document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit',validateEventHandler);
```

… but I'd rewrite `validate` so that it just used `this` and not the `form` argument.

Answer (score 0):

According to answer on this post [JavaScript code to stop form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486) I implemented `event.preventDeafault()` command to prevent submission if the field is empty.

```
<form>
  <input name="xyz">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<script>
function validate(event)
{
  if(document.forms[0].xyz.value=='')
  { 
    alert('Mandatory field!');
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit',validate);
</script>
```

Comment: There's even an article about `preventDefault()` on W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp